# head() function does not work within 'for' loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I tried using a for loop to print out a few rows. here is the code. 
Weird thing is that it doesn't work for head() function. It works if I replaced `head()` with `print()`.

```
kw_id=c('a','b')
keyword_text=data.frame(col=c('a','b'), col2=c(1,2), row.names=(c('r1','r2')))

for (i in 1:2) { 
   plot_data<-subset(keyword_text,col==kw_id[i])
   print(plot_data)
   head(plot_data)
}
```

Could someone help? I suspect it has something to do with `head()` function.

Comment: try `print(head(plot_data))`

Comment: @Arun -- You're right, of course, but do you happen to know why objects don't get printed in a `for` loop, as the do in the the REPL? Or is that "just the way it is"?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, hadn't given a thought until you asked. Joshua precisely answered this I guess.

Answer (score 15):

This is a relatively common class of problem that newcomers to R run into. The issue here is that R serves two mistresses: interactive console work and "true programming".

When you type a command at the console that returns a value, the console *automatically* calls a print method in order to display the results. When running a script, this doesn't happen unless you tell it to.

So if you changed it to `print(head(plot_data))` it should work.

These are discussed in FAQ [7.16](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-output-not-printed-when-I-source_0028_0029-a-file_003f) and [7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)

Addendum lifted from the comments:

As Josh points out, copy+pasting the for loop directly to the console also fails to print any output. What's going on in that case is that for loops (like most everything in R) is actually a function, and it's return value (`NULL`) is returned invisibly, which means no printing. (This is mentioned in `?Control`.)

Comment: But even when it's copied into the console, the `for` loop doesn't auto-print...  Seems like something else/some other design decision is at play (?) Probably just nice to avoid spewing out pages of `print`ed output for loops that iterate more than a few times.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Hmmm. Something going on where the `for` loop function is evaluated with the last statement automatically wrapped in something like `invisible`? (I don't mean that literally, just that somehow the for loop "function" isn't returning a value.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yep. It's almost certainly because `for` (and others) return NULL invisibly.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: this automagic printing (actually I believe, `show` is used) takes place only at the uppermost level of the command line (and in the `browser`). Related problems are discussed in FAQ 7.16 (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-is-the-output-not-printed-when-I-source_0028_0029-a-file_003f) and 7.22.

Comment: Joran -- Your answer's beautifully written, but I think the real explanation is in your comment: this doesn't have much to do with running scripts, but has everything to do with `for`'s return value. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Probably; I still think the explanation about console vs. script is relevant, since I think the source of the confusion from the user's perspective is that when they typed `head(data)` at the console they saw some output, but they didn't when they ran the for loop, and if all I said was "for loops return NULL invisibly" they might think the line `head(data)` in a script would work correctly.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess it's just that the message *I* take from this question is "pay attention each statement's return value", since *that* is what gets printed by the REPL -- assuming it's not assigned to a variable, or wrapped in `invisible()`.  (Scripts don't even go through the REPL, so their behavior seems like a different issue to me.)

Comment: appreciate the beautiful answers. super clear on the point of paying attention to return values for each statement.